# How to Make a Ladder Climbing Script

Tags: unity, c#, rigidbody

I'm inexperienced and I'm trying to understand the mechanism for using a ladder with my character or climbing over small walls.

To move I use a `Rigidbody`, not `Kinematic`, but with `AddForce`. I tried to create an object to simulate a ladder to climb on. To get my character into contact with the ladder I inserted a `Collider` trigger on the ladder and called the `OnTriggerStay` function.

After working a bit, I used a `bool` such that  my character can go up or down the ladder when he's close enough, but I don't understand some things.

- First of all, is the script better to put on the character or create one on the ladder?
- The second thing is once you get to the top how do I insert a function correctly and make my character complete the climb, making it arrive above the object where the staircase is located?
- Do I have to get to the top, destroy the game object and respawn at a point just above the ladder? What is the best way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
private Rigidbody rb;
public bool ladderClimb = false;
void Start()
    {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

 void Update()
    {
     if(ladderClimb){
directionRot = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);  //direction of rotation
movement = new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0).normalized; //object movement
  rb.useGravity = false;}
   else rb.useGravity = true;
}

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider){
     if(collider.gameObject.tag == "ladder"){
     if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E)) ladderClimb = !ladderClimb;}}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider){
   if(collider.gameObject.tag == "ladder") ladderClimb = false;}
```